# State variables not setting correctly, giving wrong results in 'if' condition

Tags: reactjs, state, rendering

I'm setting some state variables in a ReactJS function based on the inputs received onClick. I'm adding these to a running total, and when that total exceeds a given pre-defined level, I want to set a flag. This flag would help me do a few things subsequently, inside the function and outside of it.
The problem I'm facing is that the 'if' is not evaluating correctly, though running totals are calculating fine. I can see them on a rendered element in a div, though on console.log I see the values from the previous time the function was executed onClick.
Because of this, the flag is not getting set correctly, which is causing me much chagrin.
Would deeply appreciate help, since I'm new to the new-age programming (I'm from the dinosaur era of 3rd generation programming).
Copying the relevant piece of code below..

```
const [assessCourseList, setAssessCourseList] = useState([]);
const [flag1, setFlag1] = useState(false)
const [totqns, setTotqns] = useState(0.0);
const [totmarks, setTotmarks] = useState(0.0);


function createAssessCourse1(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTotqns(prev => { return (prev + Number(assessCourse.AC_CO_NoOfQns)) })
    setTotmarks(prev => { return (prev + Number(assessCourse.AC_CO_TotMarks)) })

    if (Number(totqns) >= Number(assessTotQns) || Number(totmarks) >= Number(assessTotMarks)) {
        
        setFlag1(true);
    } else {
        setFlag1(false);
    }
    
    if (!flag1) {
        setAssessCourseList(prev => {
            return [...prev, assessCourse]
        })
    }
    else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: `setState()` is usually asynchronous, which means that at the time you execute your if block,  the state might not updated yet. Calculate the values first and use those values in if condition and also update your state.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to use a useEffect() method to do the 'if' and set the flag